# Encoding character string to unicode

Tags: python, unicode

I am just playing with unicode I did following

```
s='ab'

s.encode('utf8')
Out[44]: b'ab'

s.encode('utf16')
Out[45]: b'\xff\xfea\x00b\x00'

s.encode('utf32')
Out[46]: b'\xff\xfe\x00\x00a\x00\x00\x00b\x00\x00\x00'
```

My question is why utf-8 is just returning the string and other encoding are returning correct output?
Should not the first encoding utf-8 return  byte encoding like utf-16 and utf-32?

Comment: what do you expect for a or b?

Comment: The output is a `bytes` (note the `b` before the quotation marks) and the UTF-8 encoding is correct. What do you expect?

Comment: @kennytm  I was expecting something like b'\x..\x.. .I mean backslash character and hex stuff where is that in utf-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was expecting something like b'\x..\x..

```
b'ab'
b'\xff\xfea\x00b\x00'
b'\xff\xfe\x00\x00a\x00\x00\x00b\x00\x00\x00'
```

Are the simplest Python representations for each sequence of bytes. `a` and `b` are included in the representations literally because that's the shorter, more readable option; the same isn't be done for byte `\x00` because that's an invisible control character.

Nonetheless you can certainly write `a` and `b` as `\x` escapes too if you like, resulting in the exactly equal literals:

```
b'\x61\x62'
b'\xff\xfe\x61\x00\x62\x00'
b'\xff\xfe\x00\x00\x61\x00\x00\x00\x62\x00\x00\x00'
```

It's an advantage and specific design goal for UTF-8 to encode Plain Old ASCII characters to single bytes without any extra null bytes or BOM signalling.

Answer (score 1):

Standard ascii characters encode to themselves in in `utf-8`. Your `utf-8` encoding is correct. That is one of the advantages of `utf-8`.